# Update two tables concurrently in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two tables: Products and Recommendations. The first 2 million records on both tables contain the same data, and then differ for about 100k records. Basically the tables contain product ids, and I need to write a script which calls an API to update each products/recommendations attributes (title, price...etc). Is it possible to update the attributes on both tables at the same time rather than updating the product models attributes, and basically using the same script to update the recommendation model?

Api Parser:

```
def get_item_info(id)
  url_raw = URI.parse("url_id=#{id}")
  url = Net::HTTP.get_response(url_raw).body
  if url.empty?
    @title        = "Product Unavailable via API"
    @prod_url     = "url"
    @cover_img    = "image"
    @price        = "Product Unavailable via API"
  else
    begin
      @response1  = JSON.parse(url)
      @title      = @response1["ProductName"]
      @prod_url   = "#{@response1["ProductUrl"]}"
      @cover_img  = @response1["ImagePath"].gsub("75X75.gif", "180X180.jpg")
      @price      = @response1["currentItemPrice"]
    rescue
    end
  end
end
```

I am currently getting this data in real time and sending it to my view. I would like to save images and titles to my db to speed up page load time. Both my products and recommendations table have the same schema, and I need to update the same columns on both tables.

Comment: What does your script and/or your api look like?

Comment: can you paste some code please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **trigger** method directly from your db.
For example, with **SQLite**

```
CREATE TRIGGER 'triggername' 
AFTER 'event' ON 'tablename' 
WHEN 'condition' 
BEGIN 
  UPDATE 'tablename2' SET 'field' = 'value' 
  WHERE 'condition';
END
```

... and you do not have to think about it !!!!